# phpMyAdmin infinite loop when attempting to use phpMyAdmin from VistaPanel on ByetHost

Tags: php, database, redirect, phpmyadmin, hosting

I am using a free host called [ByetHost](http://byethost.com/) as I don't need an expensive hosting solution for the website I am building as the traffic will be low.

I am experiencing an infinite redirect loop when attempting to sign in to phpMyAdmin in my VistaPanel account. I am using a CMS and need to backup my database.

When I attempt to enter phpMyAdmin, using the URL http://www.php-myadmin.com/login.php?phpMyAdmin=HASHINHERE I just get this in my browser:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

I have cleared all cookies and cache and tried two different browsers (FF and Safari).

Comment: If you have access to the files, grab a hold of config.php in the PMA folder and see what kind of authentication it is set up to do, password might be in there too.  If no luck I'd ask the hoster to sort this out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the way to get around this problem and I can imagine it could be an issue for other VistaPanel/cPanel users of phpMyAdmin.

I had to log into the cPanel, **change my password**, logout, clear all my cookies and then log back in. When I logged back in and tried to connect to phpMyAdmin I could get in fine!