# How to deploy phpmyadmin with http authentication and protected by an htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I'm currently using phpmyadmin with http auth.
I would like to add a security layer using a htaccess with a htpasswd, but I failed.
Whatever browser I use to test, I'm caught in an authentification loop :(

My test platform is a debian wheezy with stable release of phpmyadmin.
I haven't done any "tweaks" just configured the http auth mecanism.

I tried searching for a solution using google, but it seems I've failed too

Any clues maybe?

Comment: Coulld you try this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351895/phpmyadmin-infinite-loop-when-attempting-to-use-phpmyadmin-from-vistapanel-on-by

Comment: Generally it is a cookies issue

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? I suggest switching phpMyAdmin to the `auth_type = 'cookie';` -- at the very least, it will help you during testing to track down the problem. Once you have it working, if you then wish to have two similar-looking http authentication windows appear, you can switch it back, but I think that's a good way to confuse the user about which pop up is for which username and password.